# Modify This Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am trying to create a tikz image as follows:

Its [image: output here]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out,
inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!5]
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        % slant rectangle
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10, rounded corners=10, rotate=30] (3.0,2.8) rectangle (7.0,2.2);
    
        %% small circles
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10] (1.5,3.75) circle (0.4cm);
        \fill[Cyan] (1.5,3.75) circle (0.2cm);
    
        %%% Big Rectangles
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10, rounded corners=10] (5.0,4.4) rectangle (11.6,7.6);
        \fill[Cyan,rounded corners=10]  (4.8,4.8) rectangle (11.3,7.3);
    
        %% big circles
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10] (5.5,6) circle (1.6);
        \fill [Cyan](5.5,6) circle (0.9cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**What I Want**

I want it modified to something [image: like this]. with the sketched part been shaded to rhyme with the handle and the circular joint.

You can check [image: this also].

Let your solution be what a new bea like me can relate to (I simply need modification), as I will the using this as part of another picture.

Comment: A clue may help me in this situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does something like this suit you? If not exactly, you get the idea, just have to change a bit the dimensions.

[image: add curve on rectangle]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out,
inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!5]
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        % slant rectangle
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10,rotate=30] (3.2,2.8) -- ++ (2.5,0) to[bend right] ++ (0.65,0.4) --++ (-.05,-1.4) to[bend right] ++ (-0.65,0.4) -- ++ (-2.5,0) -- cycle;
    
        %% small circles
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10] (1.5,3.75) circle (0.4cm);
        \fill[Cyan] (1.5,3.75) circle (0.2cm);
    
        %%% Big Rectangles
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10, rounded corners=10] (5.0,4.4) rectangle (11.6,7.6);
        \fill[Cyan,rounded corners=10]  (4.8,4.8) rectangle (11.3,7.3);
    
        %% big circles
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10] (5.5,6) circle (1.6);
        \fill [Cyan](5.5,6) circle (0.9cm);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```